# Express redirect to a results page after a form post

Tags: express

I am currently working on an express application that uses handlebars to render templates for html to be delivered to the browser.

On one of the pages I have a form, this form data needs to be posted to a route in express, once the form data is received I then build a new object so I can then do a further post from express to an api, this api should then return some data back to the express app for me to then render this new data to a new view.

- So post from form to a route say '/searh'.
- In the search route I build a new object with the submitted for data.
- This new object is then posted to an api.
- This api should return some data.
- With this new data I will pass this to my handlebars template to
  render a new page showing these results

e.g. the search page is '/search' and I need to show the results in '/resuls'

I am just now sure how I can achieve this in terms of rendering a new page based off of the returned results.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Receive the form data then send a request to the api through axios then get the response, do whatever you want them send to the view .